# When i submit an EditForm(blazer dotnet 8) the values that i receive are always empty How can i fix this?

Tags: c#, blazor

I was following a tutorial about Blazor, where we were creating a game catalogue to store famous games (name,genre,price, etc).

So we created an `EditForm` so that when I submit it, it should add it to a game list object and then display it .

The thing is the values I retrieve when I bind it with to properties are all empty.

This is the Game Model class

```
    namespace GameProject.Models;

    public class Game
    {
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public required string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the `EditForm`

```
    @using Models
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    <PageTitle>New Game</PageTitle>
    <h1>Add New Game</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <EditForm Model="@game" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="a">
          <div class="mb-3">
           <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
           <InputText id="name" @bind="game.Name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
           <label for="genre" class="form-label">Genre:</label>
           <InputText id="genre" @bind="game.Genre" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">PLEASE WORK</button>
        </EditForm>
      </div>
    </div>

   @code {

      Game game = new Game(){
        Genre = string.Empty,
        Name = string.Empty
     };
    

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Submitted: Name={game.Name}, Genre={game.Genre}, Price={game.Price}");

        GameClient.AddGame(game);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new BlazorWeb App in latest version of VS 2022 .Net8 and accepted the defaults [interactive render mode: Auto...] / [Interactive location: Per page/component]. Based on the original code I created 'GamePage.razor' and placed one version in the Server Pages [@page "/gamepageserver"] and one in the Client Pages [@page "/gamepageclient"]. The only difference is the page directive and a mod to the ConsoleWriteline [Server]- / [Client-]. The main issue to get this working was to add this line at the top: @rendermode InteractiveServer to work in with the default app settings. Here is the code:

```
@page "/gamepageserver"

@*BlazorWebApp: The following line required for Interactivity*@
@rendermode InteractiveServer 

@using BlazorWebApp8Basic.Client.Pages
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>New Game</PageTitle>

<h1>GamePage</h1>

<h3>Add New Game</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <EditForm Model="@game" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="a">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
                <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="game.Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="genre" class="form-label">Genre:</label>
                <InputText id="genre" @bind-Value="game.Genre" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me - PLEASE WORK!</button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Game game = new Game();

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[Server]-Submitted: Name={game.Name}, Genre={game.Genre}, Price={game.Price}");

        // GameClient.AddGame(game);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");

    }

    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you fellow programmer this actually worked 

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use two-way binding for your input elements.

Instead of

```
 <InputText id="name" @bind="game.Name" class="form-control" />
```

try to use

```
 <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="game.Name" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: i actually tried that but still can't resolve the issue

Comment: Look at this blazor fiddle snippet https://blazorfiddle.com/s/r6xoimua
Klick run, enter a value and klick the button. Your input is reflected in the header tag

Comment: interesting ,so the issue is probably in the handlesubmit  method

Comment: I still cant find where i went wrong 